# Spill long and wide table

Tags: longtable, tabu

I have a table too long and too wide for the page. I know I can use `\longtable` to spill the table if it is too long, but how can I also spill the table if it is too wide? In this case I want it to spill both ways. I am in a landscape environment. I figure I can manually split the table but is there anyway to do it automatically?

Comment: There are several ways to solve the problem (using a smaller font size, reducing the intercolumn spacing, using  fixed width columns). The solution dpends on each particular case, so you should post a representative example.

Comment: how about specifically let the table spill to the next pages?

Comment: If you are automatically typesetting thousands of pages of database dump every day and need an automatic solution, some things are sometimes possible, but if this is a document that you are writing  then spending the time to re-arrange the data by hand will make the result far more readable. Splitting a table vertically really demands understanding of the data and re-formatting it to present two useful subsets on different pages. At best an automatic version will just arbitrarily put whatever columns fit into each page. (but there are answers on this site for splitting a table if you must)

Comment: I was answering  about the problem of too wide tables. For long tables, you have of course `longtable` or its extension to  tabularx, `xltabular`.